# Counting Occurrences Value Substrings contained in entire Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, count, substring, javascript-objects

I want to count **substrings** of object values, i.e. the entire object *contains* a string instead of a key *equals* a string.
A working Xpath in XSLT would be

> `count(//v[contains(.,current-grouping-key())])`

But i can't figure this out in javascript.

I tried the following:

```js
const obj = 
  [ { v: 'Bla Blu Bli' },
    { v: 'Bla Blu Bli' },
    { v: 'Bla Blu' },
    { v: 'Bla Bli' }
  ];

const count = obj.reduce( function(sums,entry) {
    sums[entry.v] = (sums[entry.v] || 0) + 1;
    return sums;
 },{});
 
console.log(count)
```

But this counts the exact strings only.
So I get:

```
"Bla Blu Bli": 2,
"Bla Blu": 1,
"Bla Bli": 1
```

instead of

```
 "Bla Blu Bli": 2,
 "Bla Blu": 3,
 "Bla Bli": 3
```

Is there a way to count the substrings instead of the exact values?

Comment: What do you mean by substrings? All nonempty substrings or just the ones you get after splitting on the `†` character?

Comment: What would be the result if you add `{ v: "Bla † Bli" }`?

Comment: all nonempty ..the † could be ignored too. just an example of what my data looks like.

Comment: why is ther no `"†" : 5` ?

Comment: i edited the question. the † is irrelevant. My entire object contains "Bla Blu" 3 times. Not 1 time. I am doing something wrong with the "=" here I guess but i cannot figure it out.

Comment: is `'Bla Blu Bli'` the same as `'Bla Bli Blu'` ?

Comment: Yes exactly. They should be treated the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This second version should be faster.

(you wrote *I have 100k+ values* ,  in a comment)

It creates an array only of different series, associated with the number of copies of identical series
And traverses this array by adding to this quantity those of the other sets including the same values,
by selecting only those whose size is larger.

I used Set elements because according to the doc a [set].has(value) is faster than an [array].includes(value)

```js
const obj = 
  [ { v: 'Bla Blu Bli' }
  , { v: 'Bla Bli Blu' }
  , { v: 'Bla Blu'     }
  , { v: 'Bla Bli'     }
  ];

const counts = obj
  .reduce((r,o) => // create arr with unique sets with count of copies
    {
    let 
      arr = o.v.split(' ')
    , sam = r.find(x=>(x.s.size===arr.length) && arr.every(a=>x.s.has(a)) )
      ;
    if (sam)  ++sam.n   // + one more copy
    else      r.push({arr, s:new Set(arr), n:1 })
       // next step need  arr and set to avoid losing time 
       // in conversion operations between array and Set
    return r
    },[]) 
  .reduce((c,e,_,all) =>
    {
    c[e.arr.join(' ')] = e.n  
      + all.reduce((s,x)=>((x.s.size > e.s.size && e.arr.every(a=>x.s.has(a))) ? s + x.n : s),0)
      // try to find includings, only in largest sets
    return c
    },{})  

console.log(  counts  )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use that:

```js
const obj = 
  [ { v: 'Bla Blu Bli' }
  , { v: 'Bla Blu Bli' }
  , { v: 'Bla Blu'     }
  , { v: 'Bla Bli'     }
  ];

const counts = obj
  .map(e=>e.v.split(' ').sort((a,b)=>a.localeCompare(b)))
  .reduce((r,a,_,all)=>
    {
    let terms = a.join(' ')
    if (!r[terms])
      r[terms] = all.reduce((c,x)=>c+(a.every(v=>x.includes(v))?1:0),0);
    return r
    },{})
    
console.log(  counts )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```

Comment: this works and is pretty fast:) thanks a lot!

Comment: @mr.parchman I started looking to see if there was a way to speed this up with the use of Set, I'll probably post a new answer soon

Answer (score 0):

You have to use indexOf or similar, to see if a substring exists in a string.

Example:

```js
obj = [
    {
        "v": "Bla † Blu † Bli"
    },
    {
        "v": "Bla † Blu † Bli"
    },
    {
        "v": "Bla † Blu"
    }
]

const counts = Object.fromEntries(
  obj.map(({v}) => [v, obj.reduce((acc, el) => {
    if (el.v.indexOf(v) > -1) acc++;
    return acc;
  }, 0)])
);

console.log(counts);
```

Comment: this works but unfortunately it is very slow. I have 100k+ values

Comment: This is an O(n^2) algo, I don't think you can do this any faster (?).

Comment: It should basically do the same as in https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering.html The filter + counting works very fast (miliseconds) for 100k rows. I don't know how they do it.

Comment: Not really, because if you filter for a typed in string you are searching a large array for a known value, but it's still O(n).  In your case, you are searching the array for values containing any other value in the array, so the complexity is squared.

Comment: this code is not compatible with the last update of PO values :/

Comment: @MisterJojo Yeah the question changed and your answer is fine, I don't think I will update this.